# I have a question about the tideman problem in cs50

Tags: c++, c, graph, cs50

I was doing the tideman problem in pset3(cs50), but I can't tell the difference between my programme and the correct programme of the function look_pairs.

```
:) tideman.c exists
:) tideman compiles
:) vote returns true when given name of candidate
:) vote returns false when given name of invalid candidate
:) vote correctly sets rank for first preference
:) vote correctly sets rank for all preferences
:) record_preferences correctly sets preferences for first voter
:) record_preferences correctly sets preferences for all voters
:) add_pairs generates correct pair count when no ties
:) add_pairs generates correct pair count when ties exist
:) add_pairs fills pairs array with winning pairs
:) add_pairs does not fill pairs array with losing pairs
:) sort_pairs sorts pairs of candidates by margin of victory
:) lock_pairs locks all pairs when no cycles
:( lock_pairs skips final pair if it creates cycle
    lock_pairs did not correctly lock all non-cyclical pairs
:) lock_pairs skips middle pair if it creates a cycle
:) print_winner prints winner of election when one candidate wins over all others
:) print_winner prints winner of election when some pairs are tied
```

This is my programme, I made a little difference between the correct one.Instead of judging the return of the makeCycle(winner, i), I just return this function, you can see the difference in my code.

```
bool makeCycle(int winner, int loser) 
{
        if (winner == loser) {
            return true;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i ++) {
            if (locked[loser][i]) {
                    return makeCycle(winner, i); 
            }
        }
        return false;
}

// Lock pairs into the candidate graph in order, without creating cycles
void lock_pairs(void)
{
    // TODO
    for(int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i ++) {
        if (!makeCycle(pairs[i].winner, pairs[i].loser)) {
            locked[pairs[i].winner][pairs[i].loser] = true;
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

This is the correct version, but I think my programm is the same as the correct version, I don't know why my programme will cause this mistake.

````
bool makeCycle(int winner, int loser) 
{
        if (winner == loser) {
            return true;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i ++) {
            if (locked[loser][i]) {
                    if(makeCycle(winner, i)){
                        return true;
                    }
            }
        }
        return false;
}

// Lock pairs into the candidate graph in order, without creating cycles
void lock_pairs(void)
{
    // TODO
    for(int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i ++) {
        if (!makeCycle(pairs[i].winner, pairs[i].loser)) {
            locked[pairs[i].winner][pairs[i].loser] = true;
        }
    }
    return;
}```
````

Comment: C or C++? Please [edit] your question to remove the one that's misplaced here.

Comment: Where is _the correct version_ from?

Comment: Isn't this a better fit for [cs50.se]

Answer (score 0):

In your program

```
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i ++) {
        if (locked[loser][i]) {
                return makeCycle(winner, i); 
        }
    }
```

returns `false` more often than

```
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i ++) {
        if (locked[loser][i]) {
                if (makeCycle(winner, i)) {
                    return true;
                }
        }
    }
    return false;
```

That's because in the second solution, if `makeCycle(winner, i)` fails, it doesn't return false; it continues on to the next `locked[loser][i]`.  The correct solution only returns `false` if **all** `locked[loser][i]`s can't trigger a successful call to `makeCycle(winner, i)`.  Your solution returns whatever the **first** `makeCycle(winner, i)` returns.

Comment: Thank you, your explanation is very clear.

Comment: @江定玺 I am glad you understand the differences.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The two versions are not the same.

Here:

```
if(makeCycle(winner, i)){
                        return true;
                    }
```

The function does not return when `makeCycle(..)` returns `false`. While in the first version:

```
return makeCycle(winner, i);
```

The function always returns the result of the call.

Maybe you have been mislead by

```
if (condition) return true; else return false;
```

being the same as

```
return condition;
```

But

```
if (condition) return true;
```

is **not** the same as

```
return condition;
```

The first version returns in the first iteration where `locked[loser][i]` is `true`. The second version only returns when `locked[loser][i]` and `makeCycle(...)` are both `true` and continues with the loop otherwise.

Comment: I understand the "if else" logic, but I just don't know why my code is wrong, I was stuck by the recrusive logic here.

Comment: @江定玺 Not sure if I understand waht you mean. Your code returns `makeCycle(winner,i)` when the correct version does not. Only one of them can be correct.